# Parsing a String with a GMT timezone to Date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, date, simpledateformat

I'm having problem parsing the Date from an input string that is of the following format:

```
String input = "Fri Jul 15 12:00:00 GMT+300 2011";
String dateFormat  = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(input);
```

An exception is thrown:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jul 15 12:00:00 GMT+300 2011"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

I bet it has got something to do with the GMT string. I think I've tried it with `z`, `zzz`, `zZ`, and `zzzZ`.
Any thoughts? Is the input `GMT+300` even a standard, valid input format?

Comment: I read [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone), but couldn't get it parsed.

Comment: From reading the documentation, it looks as if GMT+300 isn't valid, but GMT+3:00 would be. Is there any way you could manipulate the timezone portion of your input string first so that it's actually valid?

Comment: GMT+300 is not valid format, +0300 is

Comment: [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) can deal with this.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the String is coming directly from our UI framework's built-in form component DateItem ([SmartGWT](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateItem.html)). Maybe I'll inform the developers and wait for it to get fixed.

Comment: You could even work around the 'GMT'  part declaring it as a literal, but the +300 is an error (that's like turning 25 times around the globe, isn't it?) Either it has to become +0300 or +3:00

Comment: @anthonyg Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that `GMT+300` isn't valid GMT string according to the [Java Timezone specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone).

**Solution**: Manipulating the timezone portion of input string. `GMT+300` ==> `GMT+3:00`