# java date parsing with GMT in it

Tags: java, parsing, gmt

The published date String is returned as : Sun, 18 Nov 2012 06:50:02 GMT and my method to convertDate is returning me java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun, 18 Nov 2012 06:50:02 GMT" (at offset 8).  I checked resources but couldn't find them much helpful like this one ... [Parsing a String with a GMT timezone to Date using SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705213/parsing-a-string-with-a-gmt-timezone-to-date-using-simpledateformat)

Would really appreciate if you can shed some light on it.  Here is my method ..
pubDate here is Sun, 18 Nov 2012 06:50:02 GMT

```
public Date convertDate(String pubDate){

    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z",Locale.US);
    Date newsDate = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0).getTime();
        try{
            newsDate  = sdf.parse(pubDate);
        }catch(ParseException e){
            Log.d(Tag, "Exception Parsing date" + pubDate);
        }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `MMM` for the month field:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z",Locale.US);
```

Once this is fixed, don't forget to return `newsDate` as you're currently returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little test I did:

```
@Test
public void testDate() throws ParseException {

    String pubDate = "Sun, 18 Nov 2012 06:50:02 GMT";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
    Date newsDate = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0).getTime();

    newsDate = sdf.parse(pubDate);

}
```

You need to set the month with `MMM` because you are using the first three letters of the month (and four M would mean the [full month name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text)). Also, the timezone must be `z` instead of `Z` because you have a [ISO 8601 Time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) (GMT).