# Java parsing date with timezone from a string

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to parse a date with timezone from a string in the format `"31-12-2014 18:09 +05:30"`. I tried to parse using simple-Date-Format using `"d-MM-yyyy HH:mm ZZ"` and `"d-MM-yyyy HH:mm Z"`. But it is giving me a un-parables date exception. How to do this?
Please help me.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705213/parsing-a-string-with-a-gmt-timezone-to-date-using-simpledateformat

Comment: [check here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/)

Comment: try `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm Z` or `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm X`
why are you using `d` instead of `dd`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm XXX");
Date d = sdf.parse("31-12-2014 18:09 +05:30");
System.out.println(d);
```

Note that you can't use `X` before [SimpleDateFormat of JDK7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), because it's the ISO 8601 time zone format.

With Java 6 you can only use `ZZZ` but it won't match +05:30 because `Z` match RFC 822 time zone format

If you're using Java 6, please refer to this answer : [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date/2202300#2202300)

Comment: How to parse `Wed May 23 16:52:42 EDT 2018` date? When I put simple date format as `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss XXX yyyy` it gives `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed May 23 16:52:42 EDT 2018"` error and when I try `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss EDT yyyy` it says illegal character T which does make sense..

Comment: @AalapPatel Please read the Date and Time Patterns in the documentation referenced in my answer to understand how it works. If you still have issue you can ask a specific question if there is not already one giving you the answer in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

use X instead of Z or ZZ as below:

```
String str = "31-12-2014 18:09 +05:30";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm X");
System.out.println(format.parse(str));
Output:
Wed Dec 31 18:39:00 IST 2014
```

Comment: How to parse `Wed May 23 16:52:42 EDT 2018` date? When I put simple date format as `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss XXX yyyy` it gives `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed May 23 16:52:42 EDT 2018"` error and when I try `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss EDT yyyy` it says illegal character T which does make sense.. So what is the correct way to recognize EDT in the format ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who stumbles upon these posts:

Use `java.time` if you can, which should be the case if you are using Java 8 or higher…

Here's how to parse the example `String` from the question:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example String
    String datetimeString = "31-12-2014 18:09 +05:30";
    // formatter for that very pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm xxx", Locale.ENGLISH
                            );
    // use the formatter to get an OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(datetimeString, dtf);
    // print the result
    System.out.println(odt);
    // or print the result using the input format
    System.out.println(odt.format(dtf));
}
```

Output:

```
2014-12-31T18:09+05:30
31-12-2014 18:09 +05:30
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors: first, you should use two `d`s for the day. Second, use `X` instead of `Z` for the timezone. `X` represents the format that you are using. See the docs for more info. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm X"
```

Comment: Two `d`-s are only a must, if you always use two digits like in `01`

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the `X` option in Java SE 7. If you, however, have an older Java version, then you can change the timezone part to `+0530`, then it will work with `Z` (which is availabe even in Java SE 1.4).